# Change the default color picker box

Tags: css, angular, user-interface, angular-material, color-picker

I'm using Angular6 with material-designs. What I'm trying to do is get color input from `mat-form-field`. For that I used `matinput type="color"` inside my `input` tag. My HTML file is as follows,

```
    <div>
      <mat-form-field class="form-field">
          <mat-label>Color</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="color" formControlName="color"required placeholder="Color">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

Then I have added some CSS on it to design the color picker box according to my need,

```
input[type="color"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    float: right;
}
input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
}
input[type="color"]::-webkit-color-swatch {
    border: none;
}
```

Now the output what I'm getting is,
[image]

Even though this contains black color in default, the form field didn't get any default input. So what I want to do is get the default color box as follows. (To easily understand the requirement I have designed my expectation using photoshop),
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some styles and need some changes in ts file code to display that box

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbkqbt

Comment: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'no-color: true'. Current value: 'no-color: false'.

Comment: plese help to fix this

Comment: Can you please create stackblitz example so that I can check because I am not getting an error in my stackblitz example

Comment: I have fixed it thank you for your answer it helped me lot